# Как передать и обработать два массива в BaseAdapter

Tags: android

У меня есть `ListView` и два массива, а так же две разметки под разные массивы. Мне нужно заполнить `ListView` так, чтобы первая половина была заполнена первым массивом, а вторая вторым массивом. При создании кастомного `BaseAdapter` я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что могу обработать один массив, потому что за один проход адаптера создается только одно `View`.

**Вопрос:**

Как обработать в `BaseAdapter` два массива, при чем по очереди или как подключить к `ListView` два адаптера? 
P.S. Только не пишите "пиши свою реализацию адаптера" — я понятия не имею, как ее написать. Даже идей нет!

Comment: "Своя реализация адаптера" = "кастомный адаптер".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте так:

1. Передаёте два массива в адаптер.
2. В `getCount` возвращайте сумму длин массивов.
3. В `getView` проверяйте (по позиции исходя из длин массивов или переопределив `getItemViewType(int position)` и `getViewTypeCount())` какой массив отображать.

И лучше это делать нынче с помощью `RecyclerView`. Там несколько сложнее, чем c `ListView`, но сейчас так моднее и современнее делать)

Comment: Лучше я сначала с `ListView` разберусь, а уже потом с остальным.. =) У меня уже 90+ вопросов за одно приложение! :D